# Was Jesus being sarcastic when he called Judas "friend" in Matthew 26:50?

Tags: matthew

Judas left during the last supper. Then Jesus went to Gethsemane and prayed. After that, Jesus saw Judas again in

> Matthew 26:47 While he was still speaking, **Judas**, one of the Twelve, arrived. With him was a large crowd armed with swords and clubs, sent from the chief priests and the elders of the people. 48Now the betrayer had arranged a signal with them: “The one I kiss is the man; arrest him.” 49Going at once to Jesus, Judas said, “Greetings, Rabbi!” and kissed him.
>
> 50Jesus replied, “Do what you came for, **friend**.”
>
> Then the men stepped forward, seized Jesus and arrested him. 51With that, one of Jesus’ companions reached for his sword, drew it out and struck the servant of the high priest, cutting off his ear.

What did Jesus mean by "friend"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Matthew earlier used the same Greek word "hetairos" (ἑταῖρος):

> “But he answered one of them, ‘I am not being unfair to you, **friend**. Didn’t you agree to work for a denarius? — Matthew 20:13

and:

> He asked, ‘How did you get in here without wedding clothes, **friend**?’ The man was speechless. — Matthew 22:12

Notice that in both instances, a conflict is occurring and the speaker doesn't want it to escalate.
The usage is almost certainly ironic.

It's not unreasonable to think the same situation is happening here between Jesus and Judas.

On the other hand, Jesus may very well have considered Judas to be his friend, and so used the word in a sense of sadness, or even reassurance.

I don't think there is an obviously correct answer to this based strictly on the text and common Greek usage.
If a "true" answer is needed, I think it can only be in a doctrinal form (Christianity.SE).

Comment: Good answer. +1

Comment: Am I alone in thinking "ironic" is the wrong word here? It's probably not intended to point out that he meant the opposite, rather meant in a "despite everything I still think you're a friend" way

Comment: @JollyJoker, it felt a bit strange when I wrote it, but I can't think of a more appropriate word. "Sarcasm" seems a bit too strong though; the speaker is reminding the person of their place, but isn't trying to insult them.

Comment: @RayButterworth I think both sarcasm and irony technically mean that the opposite is implied. I'd argue the word is meant literally, as a reminder, here.

Comment: @JollyJoker, I used the word "ironic" only for the first two quotations. For 26:50 I said it might be the same situation, not that it was.

Comment: @RayButterworth Are you suggesting that Jesus, who knew for at least three years that Judas was a devil, considered Judas to be His "Friend"? Was Jesus **fooled** by Judas? Was Jesus just an easy mark? I don't get where you arrive at the notion that this was not a special  usage of ἑταῖρε.

Comment: @BillPorter, Judas wasn't a devil; [the Devil gave him an evil compusion](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/jhn/13/2/s_1010002). Jesus was all about love not hate, and forgiveness not vengeance. ¶ Remember, [Judas repented](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/mat/27/3/s_956003) and was so remorseful that he [hanged himself](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/mat/27/5/s_956005). Jesus knew this would happen and would have forgiven him.  So yes, Jesus could easily have considered him to be a friend. A friend that betrays you is still a friend, especially if they repent their actions.

Comment: @RayButterworth Go tell that nonsense to Jesus. Jesus said he was a devil. I am so amazed that the attacks upon the WORD of God is so blatant among religionists. You might well ought to attempt to instruct that slow learner, Jesus, about that **"evil compulsion"** you know so much about.

Comment: @BillPorter, I "know" nothing.  But did you bother to look at the John 13:2 link? "*… the devil having now put into the heart of Judas Iscariot, Simon's son, to betray him …*".  Isn't the Devil's putting the idea of betrayal into Judas's heart giving him an evil compulsion?

Comment: In John 15:15 Jesus explains calling people friends instead of servants. According to that you can think of "friend" as being a title or position and doesn't necessarily say anything about their character. But those of you who can read the original may be able to add.

Comment: @RayButterworth John 6:61-65 "When Jesus knew in himself that his disciples murmured at it, he said unto them, Doth this offend you? What and if ye shall see the Son of man ascend up where he was before? It is the spirit that quickeneth; the flesh profiteth nothing: the words that I speak unto you, they are spirit, and they are life. **But there are some of you that believe not. For Jesus knew from the beginning who they were that believed not, and who should betray him.**" Some of you believe not also, apparently.

Comment: @BillPorter, is your John 6:61–65 quotation an answer indicating where "*Jesus said he was a devil*" as you claimed?  I don't see it there. ¶ "*some of you believe not also*":  this is Hermeneutics.SE, where personal belief is not only not required, it is best if it doesn't enter into the answers at all.

Comment: @RayButterworth Calling Jesus and the writers of His gospels liars is part of your perverted Hermeneutics? You have that God-given right, but I have my God-given right to defend the plainspoken words of Scripture. Even Hermeneutics.SE's own new hierarchical schoolmarm has attacked **MY USE** of the plainspoken words of Scripture as being **a big assumption**. Those plainspoken words in every quarter of **real Hermeunitics** are considered as being the **first principles** of Hermeunitics.  **For Jesus knew from the beginning who they were**--profound and exacting words that mean what they say.

Comment: @RayButterworth To answer your other comment re., "what verse?" Try John 6: 70-71. "**Jesus answered them, Have not I chosen you twelve, and one of you is a devil? He spake of Judas Iscariot the son of Simon: for he it was that should betray him, being one of the twelve.**"

Comment: @BillPorter: "*Calling Jesus and the writers of His gospels liars is part of your …*".  I no longer have any idea what you are talking about, or why.  Let's end this now.

Comment: @RayButterworth NOT until I ask you why you deleted the question as to, "What verse did Jesus say he was a devil? ", that I just answered with Scripture by citing John 6:70-71. That is a cute trick, isn't it, but you are becoming known for your cute tricks. David wrote about personal attacks. **Interesting**.

Comment: @BillPorter "*why you deleted the question*".  Because the question is repeated in another comment, plus you answered it and included enough of the question that my original comment was no longer needed.

Comment: @RayButterworth Then, why did you, after seeing my answer, say that you **"no longer have any idea what you are talking about, or why"** WHILE THEN ALSO deleting your question that you claim was answered. Your actions show that you were trying discredit my response, and even more, my reputation. This cute trick is becoming quite common on this site.

Answer (score 12):

No, Jesus' words are not sarcastic.

Jesus never did any harm to Judas, only good. Tremendous privilege was bestowed upon Judas, massive potential and the best education a man could ever hope for on this earth.

Grace was continually offered, healing was ever there to be asked for, help of every kind was at hand.

Judas spent those years at the side of the Son of God, following his very steps and hearing the words which came from his own lips.

And even at the end, just moments before betrayal, Jesus called him 'Friend'.

In that very moment, Judas could have broken down, changed his path. Maybe confessed his sin of betrayal and his previous sins of theft : and been forgiven and healed.

No stumbling block was put in his path.

Even at the end, not a bad word was said to him . . . .

. . . . . and yet still he chose to transgress.

Hardened and unrepentant in the face of kindness, privilege, love and grace, Judas went out and betrayed Jesus for thirty pieces of silver.

Comment: Straightforward, crisp, and clear. Certainly deserves my upvote.

Answer (score 3):

Mat. 20:8-16, KJV shows Jesus's response to those (Jews) who murmured at the lord of the vinyard. In verse 13, notice that his answer:

> But he answered one of them, and said, **Friend**, I do thee no wrong: didst not thou agree with me for a penny? (My emphasis)

Again, in Matthew 22:12-13, the king who made the marriage for his son, after seeing a man which did not have a wedding garment, said the following:

> And he saith unto him, **Friend**, how camest thou in hither not having a wedding garment? And he was speechless. Then said the king to the servants, Bind him hand and foot, and take him away, and cast him into outer darkness; there shall be weeping and gnashing of teeth.

And, of course, after being kissed by Judas, Mat 26:50 again repeats as follows: And Jesus said unto him, Friend, wherefore art thou come? Then came they, and laid hands on Jesus, and took him.

Each of these instances reveals a special application of the word, "Friend". Remember, just a very short time earlier, Jesus, who knew Judas was to betray Him, had just washed the feet of Judas, along with the other disciples. Verse 13:10-11 is very instructive concerning that feet washing:

> Jesus saith to him, He that is washed needeth not save to wash his feet, but is clean every whit: and ye are clean, **but not all**. For he knew who should betray him; **therefore** said he, Ye are not all clean.

Then, immediately after explaining what He had just done unto them, verse 21 reveals:

> When Jesus had thus said, he was troubled in spirit, and testified, and said, Verily, verily, I say unto you, that one of you shall betray me.

One of who? This is clearly one of the special applications of the use of the word, ἑταῖρε, or Friend. Notice that most versions use an upper case "F" here, so this is indeed special. Remember, Abraham was the **"Friend of God"**, forever (2 Ch 20:7) Abraham was the father of all Jews, including David who sheds MUCH LIGHT upon this use of the word, "Friend" in the 35th Psalm, in verse 14:

> **I behaved myself as though he had been my friend or brother:** I bowed down heavily, as one that mourneth for his mother. (My emphasis)

So Jesus washed Judas' feet, as Psalm 109:4 directs:

> For my love they are my adversaries: but I give myself unto prayer.

Comment: It's worth remembering that Koine Greek has another word that is rendered as _friend_ in English translations: φιλος, and in that case its usage applies only to close associates.

Comment: @EvilSnack Yes, thank You. This is clearly not the case of a close associate, but the case of Jesus knowing for three years--at the very least--that Judas was a devil (John 6:70): Jesus answered them, Have not I chosen you twelve, and one of you is a devil?

Comment: That's a big assumption to make. [Köstenberger](https://www.biblicalfoundations.org/johannine-chronology/) for example would put John 6 only 1 year before he was betrayed.

Comment: @curiousdannii It would be foolishness to say that Jesus **learned about** Judas being a devil one year before the betrayal, when he had chosen Judas three years before the betrayal. Are you saying that Jesus did not believe the 109th Psalm? Oh, yah, Jesus was duped again. Someone in the 21st century should have been there to teach Him intelligent words. Again, what gives you the idea that Jesus only spoke about something when He finally stumbled across it? I thought you were working toward the pursuit of a Hermeneutics. THAT must have been only a **poor assumption** on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Was Jesus being sarcastic when he called Judas “friend” in Matthew 26:50?

No. The word is ambiguous. Even today, they use it ambiguous in the Middle East.

Bengel's Gnomen

> Matthew 22:12. Ἐταῖρε, comrade) A word of ambiguous meaning, which is also applied to those with whom we are not on terms of intimacy or friendship.

In the Parable of the Wedding Banquet, the "friend" is thrown out to hell just like Judah.

> Matthew 22:11“But when the king came in to see the guests, he noticed a man there who was not wearing wedding clothes. 12He asked, ‘How did you get in here without wedding clothes, friend?’ The man was speechless.
>
> 13“Then the king told the attendants, ‘Tie him hand and foot, and throw him outside, into the darkness, where there will be weeping and gnashing of teeth.’
> M